# PHP websockets with Workerman - nginx configuration

Tags: php, nginx, websocket, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use Workerman in my project, but having issues with nginx configuration. I'm using docker on my local machine and `socket.my-app.local` is translated to `127.0.0.1` in my local host file.
I've followed instructions for nginx reversed proxy, and set it up like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name socket.my-app.local;

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2020/socket.io/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2020;
    }
}
```

my PHP worker that should be websocket server is configured like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Workerman\Worker;

// Create a Websocket server
$ws_worker = new Worker("websocket://0.0.0.0:2020");

// 4 processes
$ws_worker->count = 4;

// Emitted when new connection come
$ws_worker->onConnect = function($connection) {
    echo "New connection\n";
};

// Emitted when data received
$ws_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data) {
    // Send hello $data
    $connection->send('hello ' . $data);
};

// Emitted when connection closed
$ws_worker->onClose = function($connection) {
    echo "Connection closed\n";
};

// Run worker
Worker::runAll();
```

and html file I am testing with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Workerman Sockets Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Hello</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://socket.my-app.local:2020/socket.io");

    socket.onopen = function() {
        alert("Connection established.");
    };

    socket.onclose = function(event) {
        if (event.wasClean) {
            alert('The connection is closed.');
        } else {
            alert('Connection failure'); // for example, the server process is "killed"
        }
        alert('Code: ' + event.code + ' reason: ' + event.reason);
    };

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        alert("Received data: " + event.data);
    };

    socket.onerror = function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.message);
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm unable to connect to ws server, and I'm not sure how to test, at which point it went wrong.

Could it be because `php-fpm` and `webserver` are on different docker containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was docker containers use internal namespace to communicate, so I had to change `localhost` to container name, `php-fpm` in my case, and I had to open websocket port on webserver container, as well as to listen to that port on webserver, in order to proxy those requests.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 2020;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen [::]:2020;

    server_name socket.my-app.local;

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://php-fpm:2020;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location / {
        
    }
}
```

and in my docker-compose

```
services
  webserver:
    ...
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "2020:2020"
      - "2021:2021"
```